# Confuse about recyclerview and imageview sizes

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, imageview

i'm currently using a recyclerview to display a menu consisting of an image each row.
i've created the image to be 1080 x 300 in order so it can be scale down withouth mutch issue

I can't quit understand what width options to use for the RecyclerView, and for the items layouts and imageview.  [image]
I need the image view to be, around 150dp in Height and the With to ocupy the entire screen, just like on the editor

EDIT 1:

Now theres a huge empty space between rows

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for `ImageView` in layout resource file created by yourself like custom.xml i.e. `res/layout/custom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imgItem"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Use this code for `RecyclerView` :

```
android:width="match_parent"
android:height="match_parent"
```

Comment: That do it  :). But now i have a huge blank space between each row

Comment: The spaces may be just by your picture height set background color for rootLayout to see if the background color is not showing means your images height is responsible for this gap. One more thing post your codes too so that we can see where is the mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the Scale of Image View to Center Crop or Fit XY 
Like This:

android:scaleType="centerCrop"

Answer (score 0):

**Use RecyclerView in your default activity like this**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width = "match_parent"
                android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                android:src= "" />                            

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that the height for ImageView is wrap content. This will work fine given that the height of each image is equal